# Devexpress VCL-Grid Excel filtering mode

Tags: delphi, devexpress, vcl

After upgrading Devexpress VCL from 18.2.5 to 19.1.2, in order to use the latest functions and especially the new grid Excel filtering mode,
but unfortunately, the compiler didn't recognize some constants and properties, like the dxDefaultFilterPopupWindowMode constant and
.Filtering.ColumnPopupMode property of DBGridViews.
In spite of putting dxFilterPopupWindow in the uses clause.

Any help ?

Comment: When this happens with the DevExpress library, I find the easiest thing to do is to do a Search | Find in Files to find the unit where the unrecognized item is declared and then just add the unit to my project's Uses list.

Comment: Thanks, i searched for this in the parent folder and i didn't found it.

Comment: Which parent folder do you mean?  You need to look in the Devex top-level source folder and below.  Mine is D:\DevExpress VCL\ExpressQuantumGrid\Sources for the cxGrid.  If you can't find it in yours, consider the possibility that your 19.1.2 isn't correctly installed.

Comment: Thanks again,
Mine is "C:\XE10.3/DevExpressVCL19.1.2/ExpressQuantumGrid/Sources"
When i load my app into ide and build it, it runs well without any error. But, when i try
to change the mode of gridview's filtering from default to Excel, it can't be compiled,
raising an exception with a message of <DBGridView>Filtering.ColumnPopupMode property not found !!!

Comment: But if you've searched where I suggested and not found the declaration, something must be wrong with your Devex set-up.

Comment: If i can't find a solution until tomorrow, i'll uninstall it the reinstall it again.

Comment: That's probably best, and at the same time make sure your previous Devex install isn't on your OS System path, or your project's path, and that all the previous version's DCUs are removed.

Comment: Sorry, chat isn't convenient this evening, but I think I've told you everything you need to know to fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot MartynA
(and i didn't ask for chat)

Comment: DevExpress has support forums for its products, which are free to licensed users. Have you tried asking for help there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,
This error occurred because I left the path of the previous version in the Delphi library path, and it was before the path of the new version.
So, I deleted the 1st one and I kept the new one.
Et voila, all things runs well now :):):)

Comment: I'm glad you found and fixed the problem,  Meanwhile I'd spent quite a while writing a detailed answer which includes a number of things to do, so I've posted it as an alternative answer.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY VERY MUCH MARTYN A. 
Perhaps, I can help you one day to fix a problem of Delphi, Fastreport, MySQL or Flutter

Answer (score 4):

Today I upgraded from version 18.1.2 to the most recent version of the DevExpress VCL library,
which is version 19.2.4 dated 22 January 2020 and adapted an existing minimal cxGrid
project to use the new Excel-style filtering.  It compiled and executed without any error.

Here's what I did:

1  My existing Devex install folder (the one you tell the installer to use) is  `D:\DevExpress VCL`

2  I renamed `D:\DevExpress VCL` to `D:\DevExpress VCL Prev`

3  I ran the 19.2.4 installer, giving `D:\DevExpress VCL` as the install folder to use.

You mention the compiler complains about the identifiers `dxDefaultFilterPopupWindowMode` and
`ColumnPopupMode`.  You say "In spite of putting dxFilterPopupWindow in the uses clause.

`dxDefaultFilterPopupWindowMode` is declared at line 50 of dxFilterPopUpWindow.Pas

```
const
  dxDefaultFilterPopupWindowMode: TdxFilterPopupWindowMode = fpmClassic;
```

and `ColumnPopupMode` is declared at line 3361 of cxGridTableView.Pas:

```
TcxGridTableFiltering = class(TcxCustomGridTableFiltering)
[...]
published
[...]
  property ColumnPopupMode: TdxFilterPopupWindowMode read GetColumnPopupMode write SetColumnPopupMode default fpmDefault;
end;
```

I strongly suggest that you install version 19.2.4 in the way I've described above, then check that your
project's search path includes the path to the Devex sources.  Of course, if you follow the method I've described, the project search path should not need changing, if it compiled previously.

If the compiler still complains about
not being able to find `dxDefaultFilterPopupWindowMode` and `ColumnPopupMode`, then assuming you are
**not** compiling your project to use run-time packages, the only possible cause I can think of
is that the compiler is finding earlier versions of dxFilterPopUpWindow.Dcu and cxGridTableView.Dcu that
somehow have later date stamps than the corresponding .PAS files - in that case I would delete all instances
of the Devex Dcu's from my system and try again.  A way to ensure that the compiler is compiling the
version of the Devex source files that you think it is is so edit cxGridTableView.Pas to add a "compiler stopper"
such as an exclamation mark at the very top of the file:  If the compiler does not complain about this
when trying to compile your project, you'll know that it's finding and using another version of the
cxGridTableView .Pas file or .Dcu.